# PHP form submit with Bootstrap togglable tab feature

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Hy everybody,

[this](http://www.marcellogiovenco.com/) is the website I'm building using the [Bootstrap togglable tab feature](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to handle the content I want to show (on the right side). 
My problem comes when I want to submit a contact form with php because the eventual errors are correctly shown in the Contact page but the form automatically redirects to the home page since there is no proper link to the contact page itself. The question might be silly but I cannot find a way to be redirected on the same Contact page when I submit the form. Any help?

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">           
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <h3><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">MARCELLO GIOVENCO PHOTOGRAPHY</a></h3>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">     
       <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PROJECTS</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
              <li><a href="#napoli" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">NAPOLI</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portraits" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">PORTRAITS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">BIO</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blablabla" data-toggle="tab">BLABLABLA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>  
   </div>
<!--  Content -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="myNavbar" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
          <p>home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="napoli">
          <p>napoli</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="portraits">
          <p>portraits</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bio">
          <p>bio</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
          <?php include('contact.php');?>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the **PHP** code for contact.php

```
    <?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'www.marcellogiovenco.com'; 
        $to = 'marcellomariagiovenco@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = "$name sent you a message!";

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        } else {
          $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
          // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
          if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $errName = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
          }
        }


        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You for the message! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}  
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
           <p>All fields are required.</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm- col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>    
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Its because you haven't specified "action" url or file name for form.

Comment: Even if he specified the action, the problem is that contact.php does not contain the full page html.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand , your problem is that when you click on the "submit " button is redirected to the index or to the first tab . As I ran until I got this script that redirects me to the tab where the submit button that I clicked is .

`$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.hash) {
        $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
    }
        $(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
            location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
        });
    });
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            var anchor = location.hash || $("a[data-toggle=tab]").first().attr("href");
            $('a[href=' + anchor + ']').tab('show');
});`

Hope that it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use contact.php as action for the form. Then, at the end of the if, redirect the user to a confirmation page or to the form (in case of errors) using the header() function.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how do I redirect to the form?

Comment: Use header("Location: home.php"), for example. Make sure you do not output anything before calling the function. You may also save errors in the session if you want to show them in the form. I'm writing from a tablet so I cannot be more descriptive.

Comment: The problem is that if there are errors I cannot redirect it to the same page because I have no defined URL for it and typing index.php will show the home page and not go back to the contact page.

Comment: Then you should implement a mechanism for showing the correct tab. For example, pass a GET variable to index.php containing the tab div id, then use Javascript to show it. Anyway, this is all very hacky... I would probably go the Ajax way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to submit your form with ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
                   // Show success message
                 }
    });
});
```